# Is it possible to share same view controller class between Container view controller and parent view controller

Tags: ios, viewcontroller, uicontainerview

I have a view controller which has container view and that container view has viewcontroller in storyboard I would like to use same Viewcontroller code behind for both of this.

Basically I I am creating the container view to reduce the UI Complexity.

Is it ok to do so ?

in the same way is it possible that I can have multiple containerviews and their viewcontrollers and parentviewcontroller to share same view controller

Please clarify

Comment: I guess you could nest controllers, each of which has a container view -- if you had some reason for doing it -- but eventually you'll want to show content, which would be a different kind of view controller.

Comment: Yeah.. its just to decouple the complex UI from one single storyboard viewcntroller to multiple viewcontroller

Comment: my doubt is can ..all parent and childviewcontroller share the same share view controller file .. viewcontroller1

Comment: @PhillipMills - Please leave your suggestion